# What is the correct order of elements in Haqos EX1500 External Aquarium Filter

Tags: aquarium, filters, equipment

After looking at some youtube videos and investigating this filter, I think that some info on the web is either incorrect or simply unsuitable to the HAQOS EX 1500 External Canister Filter.

What is the correct order of elements in Haqos EX1500 External Aquarium Filter?

Comment: What are the existing information and what's the issue with them?

Comment: Existing information = place foam (mechanical) filtration below bio media, because water flow direction is **assumed to be upwards**. This is not so with EX1500 which flows down.

Answer (score 3):

The HAQOS EX1500 sucks water from the sectioned tube that is build into the filtration stages and goes all the way down.
This filter circulates water through the stages from top to bottom.
Once water reaches the bottom it's sucked up via the tube. THIS IS OPPOSITE TO SOME OTHER FILTERS IN THE MARKET.
Therefore you should put carbon at the bottom, Biological media in the middle sections, and the physical filters (coarse and fine foams, and sponges) at the top. Between the foams - the coarse foam (I think it's the supplied blue) should be on top of the fine foam (Black), and if you have finer filters they should go below that.